# $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\frac{5}{3}\,\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\,\,$ $\sigma(5n)=10n$

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ a positive integer so that $$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\frac{5}{3}$$ Show that $5n$ is a perfect number i.e $\sigma(5n)=10n$.

Note: $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of all positive divisors of $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy to show that if $n$ and $\sigma(n)$ are both odd, then $n$ is a square; and that $\sigma(n)/n$ is equal to the sum of the reciprocals of the factors of $n$.  From the latter it follows immediately that
$$\hbox{if}\quad m\mid n \quad\hbox{then}\quad
  \frac{\sigma(m)}{m}\le\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}\ .$$
Now suppose that
$$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}=\frac53\ .\tag{$*$}$$
Since
$$\frac{\sigma(6)}{6}=2>\frac53\quad\hbox{and}\quad
  \frac{\sigma(45)}{45}=\frac{26}{15}>\frac53\ ,$$
neither $6$ nor $45$ is a factor of $n$.  From $(*)$ and the aforementioned results we obtain
$$3\mid n\quad\Rightarrow\quad \hbox{$n$ is odd}\quad\Rightarrow\quad
  \hbox{$n$ is a square}\quad\Rightarrow\quad 3^2\mid n\quad\Rightarrow\quad
  5\not\mid n\ ,$$
and so we can use multiplicativity:
$$\sigma(5n)=\sigma(5)\sigma(n)=6\Bigl(\frac{5n}{3}\Bigr)=10n\ .$$
Thus $5n$ is perfect.

**Comment** ...and of course $5n$ is odd.  At present, the existence of odd perfect numbers is an unsolved problem ;-)